# relative positioning of flexbox and fixed children

Tags: css, flexbox

i have some trubles with positioning elements while using flexbox.
Here is my example close to real situation i have https://jsfiddle.net/383p73L1/4/

The problem is `display: fixed` element takes all content width instead of his parents width, that has `position: relative`. How is this possible and what i missed?

Comment: it has the normal behavior for `position: fixed`, what you want to  do with that element?

Comment: in your case, remove the body margin and it will be ok

Comment: Hmmm, BLUE box has fullscreen width. And i think it should take his RED parent's width..

Comment: fixed means relative to view port so 100% width mean 100% width of your screen AND not his parent... and you have margin on body so you element will have more with than the  body by 16px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by using

```
position: sticky; 
top: 0;
```

The fixed value is similar to absolute as it can help you position an element anywhere relative to the document (not parent).

You can read about positioning elements at -> 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: @user1128677 pay attention to support of sticky https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky